# Solve the following recurrence relation: $S(1) = 2$; $S(n) = 2S(n-1)+n2^n, n \ge 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrence relation:
$$\begin{align}
S(1) &= 2 \\
S(n) &= 2S(n-1) + n 2^n, n \ge 2
\end{align}$$

I tried expanding the relation, but could not figure out what the closed relation is:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
|   n   |  S(n)                                          |
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
|   1   |  2                                             |
|   2   |  2S(1)+2*2^2 = 2*2 + 2*2^2 = 2^2 + 2*2^2 =     |
|       |              = 4 + 8 = 12                      |
|   3   |  2S(2)+3*2^3 = 2*(2^2 + 2*2^2) + 3*2^3 =       |
|       |              = 8 + 16 + 24 = 48                |
|   4   |  2S(3)+4*2^4 = 2*(2*2^2 + 2*2*2^2 + 3*2^3) +   |
|       |              + 4*2^4 =                         |
|       |              = 16 + 32 + 48 + 64 = 160         |
|   5   |  2S(4)+5*2^5 = 2*(2*2*2^2 + 2*2*2*2^2 +        |
|       |              + 2*3*2^3 + 4*2^4) + 5*2^5 =      |
|       |              = 32 + 64 + 96 + 128 + 160        |
|       |              = 384 + 96 = 480                  |
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
```

**Edit**: is it $S(n)=2^n\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: Let me pick n = 5; $S(5)=2^5 \frac{5(6)}{2} = 32 \times 15 = 16 \times 30 = 480$. Let me try n = 1; $S(1) = 2^1 \frac{1(2)}{2} = 2$.

Comment: I would like to ask for clarification.  In my solution, I used the recurrence relation that you wrote at the beginning of your question, but this is different than the one in your title (and looking more closely, the one in your table is the one in your title and not the one in your table). Which relation did you mean?

Comment: @Aaron Corrected the recurrence relation at the beginning of the question. It was missing a 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $S(n)=2+2(2^2)+3(2^3)+\cdots+n(2^n)$.  However, we can simplify the problem slightly by generalizing: replace $2$ with $x$ to get

$$f_n(x)=x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+ nx^n = x(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+nx^{n-1})=x \frac{d}{dx}(1+x+\cdots+x^n)$$

Now, using the formula for a geometric sum, $1+x+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, and differentiating we have

$$f_n(x)=x \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)=x\frac{(1-x)(-(n+1)x^{n})+(1-x^{n+1})}{(1-x)^2}$$

Plugging back in with $x=2$, we have $$S(n)=f_n(2)=2((n+1)2^n+1-2^{n+1})=2((n-1)2^n+1)=(n-1)2^{n+1}+2.$$

---

I believe there was a typo in the problem, I solved $S(1)=2;S(n)=S(n-1)+n2^n$, which was the formula in the problem but not in the title.  What follows is a solution the the recurrence in the title.

Let $T(n)=S(n)/2^n$.  Then dividing the formula $S(n)=2S(n-1)+n2^n$ by $2^n$, we get

$$T(n)=T(n-1)+n,\qquad T(1)=1.$$

Plugging in and using the standard formula for triangular number, $T(n)=1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.  Thus, $S(n)=n(n+1)2^{n-1}$

Answer (score 4):

Given
$$
S(n)=2S(n-1)+n2^n\tag{1}
$$
Consider $T(n)=2^{-n}S(n)$. $T(1)=1$ and, multiplying $(1)$ by $2^{-n}$, we have the recurrence
$$
T(n)=T(n-1)+n\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, $T(n)=\frac{n^2+n}2$ and thus,
$$
S(n)=(n^2+n)\,2^{n-1}\tag{3}
$$

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?